# AngularJS: Componentizing a form

Tags: angularjs, oop, design-patterns

I have two forms that are visually 90% the same, and the backing code for the forms are 90% the same.  Therefore, I have about **90% duplicated code** between the two, and I'd like to eliminate that.

In my set-up, I have one model that two other models extend.  The forms (views) are just projections of these models, and their input elements map to the fields of each model.

Illustrated:

```
 ____________________________
|          Base Model        |
------------------------------
      |                |
      |                |
 _____________    _____________
| Sub Model A |  | Sub Model B |
---------------  ---------------
      |                |
      |*projected with*|
 _____________    _____________
| Form A      |  | Form B      |
---------------  ---------------
```

As I mentioned before, the models A and B are about 90% identical (which is why they are inheriting from the base model to begin with).  The models implement methods `save()`, `load()`, and `destroy()`, which automatically talk to my back-end to correctly update the persisted state of the represented object.

Models A and B each have a controller that implement methods that modify data on the model.  There is one controller for model A and one controller for model B--these controllers, much like the models, are 90% the same.  These controllers drive the core functionality of the form (doing things such as setting up dropdowns, fetching additional data, initializing click handlers, etc...).  They each implement a `save()`, which simply calls the `save()` method on the corresponding model.

To reiterate, my problem is that **90% of the code is duplicated** since the two models are 90% the same

**Short example:**

say I have an input element group that has two inputs: `First Name` and `Last Name`.  Also assume that I want to check my database to ensure that the `Last Name` value already exists.

The `save()` method for model A will:

- Check the database for the `Last Name` value, and create it if it does not exist
- Save the name as `<First Name> <Last Name>`

The `save()` method for model B will:

- Check the database for the `Last Name` value, and create it if it does not exist
- Save the name as `<Last Name>, <First Name>`

Now I have duplicated code in the find-or-create of the `Last Name`.  With bigger and more complicated form fields, this code duplication grows out of control.  This does not even consider the controllers, which also have duplicated code that would do something such as setting up an autocomplete typeahead box for the `Last Name` input.

There are also multiple types of overlap:

1. The case above, where the models are the same field names but can be formatted and processed differently
2. Where one model has a field that the other model does not
3. Where both models have the same field and are processed the same way

**My initial attempt**, which ended up failing, was to create a view and controller for *each* component of the form.  I had two main views (one for each model) that used `ng-include` to include each form component.  The `ng-include` would specify the controller that would implement a `save()` and `load()`, which the parent controller would call.

Example:

```
<ng-include
  src="'app/forms/name.htm'"   <--- view HTML for the name component
  ng-controller="FormNameController"   <--- controller for the name component
></ng-include>
```

My idea was to have each of these component controllers implement:

- A `save()` method that knows how to persist the information it knows about
- A `load()` method that knows how to load the information it needs to know

And then I would use the controller for the entire page to call the `save()` and `load()` methods of all the component controllers.

I had 2 main problems (among many small problems) with this approach:

1. I couldn't figure out an elegant way to have the parent controller automatically be aware of the existence of the component controllers.  There seemed to be some strange method with `broadcast`, `emit`, and `on`, but it seemed very hacky (as I also need the `save()`, `load()` methods on the component controllers to return promises
2. It is messy having the (many) component controllers saving/loading data by themselves and then having them update the model that the main controller backs

Being that I'm using a framework (AngularJS), I would assume that there is some sort of "Angular" way to do this efficiently.  I looked around for a good way to do this for a fair amount of time, but couldn't find anything.

Any help, input, or push in the right direction would be extremely appreciated. I wasn't sure whether to post this here or on programmers.stackexchange.com; hopefully this is the right place.

Answer (score 0):

The Angular way to do this would be to use Services.
You can factor out much of your controller logic into a service to keep your controller clean and keep code reusable.

for example, and without assuming too much about your implementation.

```
app.factory('baseService', [function(){
  var base = {};
  base.save = function(data){
    //persist data      
  };    
  base.findOrCreate = function(value){
    //...
  }
  return base;
}]);

app.factory('aService', ['baseService', function(baseService){
  var a = {};
  a.save = function(aModel){
    baseService.findOrCreate(aModel.lastName);
    //do something
    baseService.save(aModel);
  };
  return a;
}]);

app.controller('aController', ['$scope', 'aService', function($scope, aService){
  //...
  $scope.save() = function(){
    //...
    aService.save($scope.aModel);
  };
}]);
```